# Set a default CC email address in Gmail

Tags: windows-7, chrome, gmail

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension/script, or Windows 7 program that can set a default CC email address in Gmail (I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate). I send emails using the Gmail web interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GmailAutoBcc](http://jaidev.info/hacks/gmailAutoBcc) does exactly this.

It's a userscript compatible with Chrome/Firefox that allows you to set a default BCC OR CC address in Gmail.

To use in Chrome, install Tampermonkey (a userscript manager), and then the script.

To configure whether you want BCC or CC, go to the script in Tampermonkey and on line 100, replace `header = "bcc";` with `header = "cc";` and on line 101, replace `GM_setValue ('gBccHeader', "bcc");` with `GM_setValue ('gBccHeader', "cc");`. Hint: To quickly find this section, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> and search for `gBccHeader`; it's the 2nd and 3rd `gBccHeader` you're looking for.

To choose the address you want to BCC/CC, the first time you click 'Send' on a Gmail compose window, it will prompt you for the address and from then on, it will automatically use that address.

Note: It auto-adds the address when you click 'Send'.

To change to BCC/CC:
[image]